# Extra whitespace appears next to img in Firefox

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using max-width:100%; and max-height:100%; for my img tag. There's a container around the img, and for some reason extra whitespace appears next to the image, on the right.

[image]

The container's width is not fixed, so it should be the same, like the image + 15px padding on every side.

CSS

```
    *, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  height:100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1450/600/"></li>
</ul>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJJqzo

Comment: Try to use height:auto and width:100% (img)

Comment: @notulysses that still gives the extra padding in FF

Comment: Are there any images SMALLER than the width of the `li`? If not, just use `width` in stead of `max-width` on the `img`.

Comment: I would like to keep the ratio, with width:100%; its not possible.

Comment: It seems to be the box-sizing on the image that's causing the issue in FF.

Comment: Yes, so it looks like a bug and I would like to find a solution to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want same padding without changing width. Comment following CSS:

```
/*-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;*/
```

[**See DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JddpRo) showing same output in *FF* and *Chrome*.

Comment: I need the border-box property. I would like to reduce the size with 15px on all side

Comment: @user1452062 So reduce the height with 30px then.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JddpWd

Comment: Honestly I would like to find a solution to fix this issue in firefox without removing any of my styles.

Comment: After using `box-sizing: content-box;` you can use any height you want. I think this is best solution for your situation.

Comment: Is it possible with border-box? I don't want to remove/modify the original styles.

Comment: @user1452062 You will have to change SOMETHING from your style, since this is causing the issue. If you change `box-sizing` to `content-box` for the specific element that is causing this issue, you will keep the changes to a minimun however. Like in my example.

Comment: @user1452062 yes adding `box-sizing: content-box;` to `li` is better.

Comment: This solution can solve the problem, but I would like to understand why is it happens in Firefox. In chrome my code works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below css :

```
li {
    background: lightblue none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 204px;
}
img {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not the solution. Please don't modify the width and the height.

Comment: ok now please try this code: 
 li {
    background: lightblue none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 20%;
}  If you won't fix li width then it will be show on full screen.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to do something like this:

```
li {
padding: 0px;
}

img {
padding: 0px;
}
```

Since you say the image doesn't need to have a modified size, simply removing the padding could be one way to remove the white space.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS reset, it will fix everything like this that you may encounter. I suggest Eric Meyer's.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a width to the li.

```
li{ width:200px; }
```

Comment: I don't want fixed width, I would like responsive image in height and width.

Comment: you could use % instead of pixel.  width: 17%